# Input type="tel" pattern stopped working after Chrome 114

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, input, tel

I have a HTML form with a telephone input. I have created a regex pattern that I believe suit my needs.

```
<input type="tel" pattern="(\+\d{2})?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})"/>
```

The pattern [is correct](https://regex101.com/r/P6KzvX/1), according to my understanding.

However, if you test it with an erroneous value like `qqqqq`, the field validation succeeds and the form is posted, since **Chrome version 114**. With Chrome versions up to 113, the validation failed saying, `Please match the requested format`. If you switch the pattern to something simpler like `[0-9]{10}`, the validation works normally.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug in Chrome?

1: https://regex101.com/r/WWKtna/1

Comment: In short: you need to escape the literal `-` inside the character classes since the `input` pattern regex is now compiled with the `v` flag.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew. Will that work for versions earlier than 113, too?

Comment: Yes, escaping a literal hyphen inside character classes works the same across all JS patterns.